# How do I make this query on a datatable?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, datatable

I wrote a couple queries in SQL thinking that I would be able to use them (or a slightly altered version of them) to query a datatable in C#. Turns out that this isn't the case. Can anyone help me to convert the below queries into something that can be used to query a datatable? I've tried using linqer but I'm not able to connect to the database with it for security reasons.

```
SELECT ag.ID 
FROM [CONTENT].[dbo].[Aggregated_bak] ag
LEFT JOIN [CONTENT].[dbo].[Records_bak] hw ON hw.ID = ag.ID 
WHERE (ag.TYPE ='A') AND hw.ID IS NULL)


SELECT hw.* FROM [PHP-CONTENT].[dbo].[Records_bak] hw 
LEFT JOIN [PHP-CONTENT].[dbo].[Records-Aggregated_bak] ag ON ag.ID = hw.ID 
WHERE ag.Id IS NULL";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
ag.Type = isnull(’A’,null) and hw.id is null

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit?